# проблема с добавлением sitemap

Tags: php, sitemap, google-search-console

Описываю проблему, у меня сайт держится на одном index.php, который перенаправляет все запросы относительно заданного url — `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Столкнулся с проблемой с sitemap: гугл не видит файл. Вот код:

*index.php*

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
    $Page = 'index';
} else {
    $URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
    $Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    $Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    if (!empty($Module)) {
        $Param = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++) {
            $Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
        }
    }
}

if ($Page == 'index') include('glavnaya.php');
else if ($Page == 'sitemap') include('sitemap.xml')
```

*sitemap*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://blabla.rf.gd/</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-03-10</lastmod>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://blabla.rf.gd/login</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-03-10</lastmod>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://blabla.rf.gd/register</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-03-10</lastmod>
        <priority>0.6</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://blabla.rf.gd/Serial</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-03-10</lastmod>
        <priority>0.7</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://blabla.rf.gd/Serial/element/</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-03-10</lastmod>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://blabla.rf.gd/profile</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-03-10</lastmod>
        <priority>0.4</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Я search console пробовал найти его у себя на сайте двумя способами — [вот так](http://blabla.rf.gd/sitemap) и [вот так](http://blabla.rf.gd/sitemap.xml).
В первой попытке search console не нашел файл. А во второй файл вроде был найден, но пустой.

Comment: потому что xml файл нужно выводить (echo или print), а не инклудить